# Geotiff based mbtiles generation using Geoserver WPS process

Tags: geoserver, mbtiles

When I tried to generate a mbtile using wps request builder, I am getting the following error:

> "Feature not available."

But the particular layer is in the form of geotiff and came to know that the

> "feature cannot be added to geotiff based layers".

Please correct my understanding and how can I generate mbtiles based using WPS process in this situation.

Note:

> I am using "WPS request builder" (WPS process) of Geoserver admin and
>   select gs:Mbtiles process from drop down list. This will display a
>   form to enter layer name, crs system, bounds, min zoom and max zoom.
>
> Then clicks on "Execute Process" and I am getting the above error.

Comment: how are you creating the tiles?, where do those errors occur? is this WPS or REST?

Comment: WPS. I have updated my question with notes in it,